# Tab bar not using full width on iOS11 iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

I'm using a `UITabbarViewController` in a relatively simple way. My issue **only** appears on iPad devices of iOS11 version. It's not visible on iOS10 or iPhone.

[image]

If you look at the screenshot, you can see that the background color of the tab is not aligned. Actually, it is aligned, it's the tabbar itself that is not taking the full width. So the background color is overlapping towards the central button because it's not using the space on the far left and far right.

I'm assuming that the tabbar is broken (and not my background colors, which are drawn manually) because the edges of the outsides tabs are not clickable, and yet the item positioning is set to be filling the width of the screen :

`TabBar.ItemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioning.Fill;`

The items sizes are wrong if you consider the tabbar fullscreen, but they are if you consider the "reduced" version. So i'm pretty sure it's all good there, as long as the tabbar decides to take the full width of the screen, the buttons and background color will then have the correct measurements.

I've tried using `View.LayoutIfNeeded()` and `SetNeedsLayout()` to force a redraw, but to no avail.

I'm not sure why it's even behaving like so, and since it's the default behaviour of the OS and I haven't done anything particular, I'm not certain of what can even be tried.

Here's some relevant code :

```
MainTabbarController tabController = (MainTabbarController)Window.RootViewController;



public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();
    ConfigureTabbar();
}


public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    UIViewController[] tabs = //Create the VCs in the most basic way

    SetViewControllers(tabs, false);
}

protected virtual void ConfigureTabbar()
{
    TabBar.Translucent = false;
    TabBar.ItemPositioning = UITabBarItemPositioning.Fill;
    TabBar.ItemSpacing = 0;

    //View.LayoutIfNeeded();
    float tabbarItemWidth = (float)Math.Ceiling(View.Bounds.Width / TabBar.Items.Length) + 1; //+ 1 to avoid the right pixel that was not filled on the right tab. Strange behaviour...
    TabBar.ItemWidth = tabbarItemWidth;
    //var version = NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.OperatingSystemVersion;
    NSOperatingSystemVersion ios11 = new NSOperatingSystemVersion(11, 0, 0);

    if (NSProcessInfo.ProcessInfo.IsOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion(ios11))
    {
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.UserInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
        {
            TabBar.SelectionIndicatorImage = _viewModel.Styles.Colors.ActiveTabColor.ToNative().ToImage(new CGRect(0, -View.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom, tabbarItemWidth, TabBar.Frame.Height));
        }
        else
        {
            TabBar.SelectionIndicatorImage = _viewModel.Styles.Colors.ActiveTabColor.ToNative().ToImage(new CGRect(0, -View.SafeAreaInsets.Bottom, tabbarItemWidth, TabBar.Frame.Height));
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
       TabBar.SelectionIndicatorImage = _viewModel.Styles.Colors.ActiveTabColor.ToNative().ToImage(new CGSize(tabbarItemWidth, TabBar.Frame.Height));
    }


    UITextAttributes attrs = new UITextAttributes();
    attrs.Font = _viewModel.Styles.Fonts.ExtraSmall.ToNative();
    attrs.TextColor = _viewModel.Styles.Colors.ActionText.ToNative();

    UITabBarItem.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(attrs, UIControlState.Normal);

    for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
    {
        UITabBarItem item = TabBar.Items[i];
        item.Title = _viewModel.Titles[i];
        item.TitlePositionAdjustment = new UIOffset(0, -4);
        item.ImageInsets = new UIEdgeInsets(-2, 0, 2, 0);
    }

    //View.LayoutIfNeeded();
}
```

Comment: Could you share code for drawing of the tab bar?

Comment: I added the relevant code ; everything important should be in the last method `ConfigureTabbar()` Which is getting worse every second I try something new